# How to Capture Node Screenshot programmatically in an Electron app

Tags: dom, electron, screenshot

Chrome has a feature to capture a screenshot of a DOM element, this feature is called **Capture Node Screenshot**:

[image]

And unlike the browser's Print function, it produces a WYSIWYG png image. **How can I trigger this function from an Electron app?**

I know for sure that my Electron app is capable to taking such screenshots since I can manually do so, but I need to do the same programmatically.